# android bootanimation

Tags: java, android, android-source, boot-animation

I'm doing android porting ,

I wanna modify android framework to make boot animation loop infinitely

so I modified  the 「desc.txt」 in the bootanimation.zip as following :

480 360 1
p 0 0 part0

I set loop value to 「0」 for infinitely loop , until boot completed.

but when system boot completed , it always stopped the boot animation , and enter the 「home app」.

could someone tell me how to make bootanimation loop infinitely.

Comment: what's android framework? where's boot animation?!?!

Comment: "how can i" - This question lacks detail and is poorly worded, indeed.

Comment: boot animation path : /data/local  ,  if there is no bootanimation.zip in this directory , it always uses default boot animation.

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer :

SurfaceFlinger.cpp

```
void SurfaceFlinger::bootFinished()
{
    const nsecs_t now = systemTime();
    const nsecs_t duration = now - mBootTime;
    LOGI("Boot is finished (%ld ms)", long(ns2ms(duration)) );  
    mBootFinished = true;

    //property_set("ctl.stop", "bootanim"); //mark this line
}
```

then you will see the boot animation loops forever.

by the way , remember to set the loop count in desc.txt to '0',

240 320 3

p **0** 0 part0